# Oracle Audit Vault and Database Firewall on Hyper-V

Tags: hyper-v, oracle

I am trying to configure an Oracle Database Firewall / Audit Server as virtual machines on Hyper-V. The problem is that, for example, to install the Database Firewall on a virtual machine, the VM needs to have at least two NIC-s (up to three). During the installation process, no NIC-s (0) are detected. Normally the NICs are configured to work within a previously created virtual network (that is working with other existent virtual machines). So, my question is the following: Are there any incompatibility issues with Hyper-V and Oracle AVDF ? I have succeeded this task with VMware. All VM are running there, that's why I'm concerned about incompatibility with Hyper-V.

Comment: I suggest you to use Oracle on Xen Cloud Platform or Xenserver?

Comment: What OS does the AVDF run on? I don't believe the Oracle Linux version is officially supported on Hyper-V at this point.

Comment: The AVDF runs on Oracle Linux, and yes, it's not supported by Hyper-V (officially), but the non-detection of NICs occurs during installation of AV Server, before installing Oracle Linux.It just checks for the minimum HW requirements, before installing anything.

Comment: @bobby6 At this moment I have to try this on Hyper-V, it's a requirement (so, not depending from me).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm going to assume that you have already added NIC's to the VM. Because that is too obvious.

Hyper-V can present 2 different kinds of NIC's to a VM: a Synthetic NIC or an Emulated NIC. A Synthetic NIC requires a Microsoft driver to work, whereas an Emulated NIC shows up as an Intel 21140 NIC that is more likely to be supported.

You get better performance with Synthetic, but if your platform doesn't support it then you have to use Emulated.

If you're using Hyper-V manager instead of Virtual Machine Manager, then Synthetic is just called Network Adapter and Emulated is called Legacy.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. You got it right, I have added NICs to the VM and I am using Hyper-V manager. Actually I have added two network adapters (so it would be Synthetic NICs). I have to check tomorrow to see if it works with Emulated NICs.

Comment: Well, it seems that it worked :). Thank you again.

Comment: Hmmm... I have a new problem now. Audit Vault Server is installed and and running on its VM, but there is a problem with the NICs. I can't access the server through its IP address. It seemed obvious in fact even during installation because an error was shown `Driver Tulip, link not detected` (something like that actually). Again, it's "working" with legacy network cards...

Comment: Hyper-V nics will show no link if they are set to "not connected". Check to make sure you connected them to a network.

Comment: Sadly they are connected to an existing network.

Comment: Start a new question. Include things like dmesg output and screen shots of your Hyper-V configuration.

Comment: Asked the question, tomorrow I will have the opportunity to add extra information to it. http://serverfault.com/questions/515416/cant-access-oracle-audit-server-interface-nics-are-not-linked-hyper-v-manager